# Seeing adverts in Serverfault but not superuser, meta or stackoverflow

Tags: support, login, advertising

I have noticed that ads are appearing for logged in users on Serverfault, but none of the other sites. Is this an issue for me or everyone?

Comment: **SHHH!! If we don't tell them they won't notice!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ads are displayed based on your reputation

#### See

- Reduced advertising

on FAQ of each sites.

Comment: According to his rep, he should be seeing the same number of ads on both SuperUser and ServerFault, but he says that this isn't the case.