# Privilege/FAQ pages should not show ad reduction privilege on SE sites that don't actually show ads

Tags: feature-request, reputation, privileges, faq-update-request, site-faq

According to the Meta [privileges page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges) regarding [ad reduction](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/privileges/reduced-ads), I am as I write this about 98% of the way towards reaching this privilege. After discussing here a bit, I've also discovered that the [FAQs (for Meta and other sites)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) even says that this is a perk I'm soon to receive. However, I currently don't see any ads at all, and I do not use any ad-blocking utilities.

<sub>Don't get me wrong, I don't mind at all not seeing any advertising!</sub>

[This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/51244/179372) briefly mentions missing ads from Meta, but it is an older question, and this site specifically was not really addressed in the answer.

[Does Meta just not have ads?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/90002/179372) If so, then why have so much information regarding the reduction of ads in the new user information? The answer in the just-mentioned link doesn't really answer this question to my satisfaction.

Why don't we just remove the ad reduction piece entirely from FAQs of this and/or these other sites? Does everyone else disagree and think that we should keep this in place?

Comment: Who would you target on a meta if you were paying for it?

Comment: @random I'm not saying we *should* have ads. I'm suggesting the privilege and/or and FAQ-related content regarding the priv be removed for Meta.

Comment: Pill poppers. The answer is uppers and downers.

Comment: What's not satisfactory about the answer there? The page exists on Meta so it can be edited for the other sites which happen to make use of that privilege.

Comment: I'd like to advertise my unicorn plush toys here on Meta.

Comment: I'll buy one.  Along with one of Pekka's genuine Gucci handbags.

Comment: @TimStone I see no ads on [this](http://android.stackexchange.com), [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com), or [this](http://askubuntu.com) site, even though I don't even have accounts here. So while the `template` idea is presented, it doesn't really seem to apply.

Comment: It applies to the "other sites which happen to make use of that privilege" , which are Stack Overflow, Server Fault, and Super User. The other sites in the network do not make use of that privilege, because they don't have those ads.

Comment: Right, so then why do the FAQs for these site *also* include the privilege? ([1](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)) ([2](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation)) ([3](http://askubuntu.com/faq#reputation))

Comment: Presumably because it was adapted from the original FAQ on one of the trilogy sites which have that privilege, and no one realised that mistake. I'm not sure if it's possible to remove that line from the FAQ on a per-site basis, but I agree it would make sense to do so for all of the other sites.

Comment: They may show ads, but we don't know when. So it's still valid to include the line

Comment: @random You mean they display at random times, or they will be present at some yet undefined point in the future?

Comment: It would be the latter right now