# Why does Meta Stack Exchange have privileges that don't have any effect?

Tags: support, meta, privileges, privileges-page

On Meta Stack Exchange, I've noticed two privileges that don't make any difference on this site, but that are still listed on the [privilege page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges).

One of these is the [reduced ads](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/reduced-ads) privilege. This privilege is irrelevant on meta since there still aren't any ads on meta, as stated in the help center:

> Meta sites have no advertisements so this privilege is not relevant for them.

The other such privilege is the [participate in meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/participate-in-meta) privilege. This privilege is irrelevant to Meta Stack Exchange since this site itself is meta and has no other meta site associated to it.

However, both these privileges are listed on the privilege page of Meta Stack Exchange and can be tracked as the next privilege on the profile page. Is there any reason to this?

Comment: Technical matter: the privileges page is the same across all main sites, and MSE is also considered a main site since it got reputation of its own, etc.

Comment: @ShadowWizard But on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges), there are documentation privileges listed that aren't listed on other sites.

Comment: Stack Overflow is... different. It's also going to get a top bar of its own very soon, so it won't be part of Stack Exchange, design-wise. I am pretty sure the rest of the privilege pages are still using the same "template" and changing that would simply be too much work to be worth the efforts.

Comment: Not only does MSE share the templates all other network sites (except SO and A51) use as @ShadowWizard said, it *is* the template source. So everything normal sites use has to be present here.

Comment: And [Privilege/FAQ pages should not show ad reduction privilege on SE sites that don't actually show ads](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138056/privilege-faq-pages-should-not-show-ad-reduction-privilege-on-se-sites-that-don)

Comment: @hichris123 No, the first question is about Meta Stack Overflow and my question is about Meta Stack Exchange. The second question is similar to this one, but not exactly the same since it's a feature request asking to remove the privilege and my question is asking why the privilege is there without asking to change anything, and it's only about the ads and not about the meta privilege. Besides, it doesn't have any answer.

Comment: In the beginning there was no Meta Stack Exchange, only Meta Stack Overflow. Now MSE is what MSO **used to be**, and MSO is a brand new meta site, 100% ordinary per-site meta of SO. That's it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, then it's kind of a duplicate. That question doesn't say anything about ads, but it's still possible to figure out from the answer that it concerns the ads too. I think that maybe it would be useful to edit that question and answer to make it explicit that what they call MSO is now MSE. Tell me if that's the right thing to do so that if it is I can suggest an edit.

Comment: Well, it's closed as duplicate too, and the root is newer, and does use the new terms. So not 100% sure we need to edit.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I still think it should be edited, since it's confusing otherwise. People can have a hard time figuring out why it's a duplicate of the other question and why this question is a duplicate of it. But if it really shouldn't be edited, I won't edit it, maybe it could be useful to add a comment instead.

Comment: Feel free to suggest an edit, good chance it will be approved.